# jQuery appendTo moving other elements as a fix in Polymer adds other elements unintentionally

Tags: jquery, polymer, append, element

Edit: I just realized those paper material elements have the same class name as the one I'm trying to move. I'm going to give the div I'm trying to move an ID and move it with that instead. On break now, but will try it when I get back and update with results.

I'm using Polymer 1.0, and the Chrome browser reorders the elements incorrectly when the page is loaded. Other browsers work fine.

Here's my shorthand version of the html in Chrome. The "content" class div is supposed to be in the div with id "mainContainer".

```
<paper-scroll-header-panel fixed="" class="x-scope paper-scroll-header-panel-0">
<div id="mainContainer" class="style-scope paper-scroll-header-panel" style="top: 0px;"></div>
<div id="headerContainer" class="style-scope paper-scroll-header-panel" style="transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px);"></div>
<paper-toolbar role="toolbar" class="x-scope paper-toolbar-0"></div>
<div class="content"></div>
</paper-scroll-header-panel>
```

As a fix, I decided to use jQuery's appendTo method to move "content" into "mainContainer":

```
document.addEventListener('WebComponentsReady', function(){
    var content = $( ".content" ).detach();
    content.appendTo( "#mainContainer" );
}
```

However, after doing so, it moves additional paper-material elements that exist outside of my paper-scroll-header-panel into "mainContainer".

```
<div id="mainContainer" class="style-scope paper-scroll-header-panel" style="top: 0px;">
<script src="headerBarJS.php" type="text/javascript"></script>
<paper-material animated="" class="content  style-scope paper-button x-scope paper-material-0" elevation="0"></paper-material>
<paper-material animated="" class="content  style-scope paper-button x-scope paper-material-0" elevation="0"></paper-material>
<paper-material animated="" class="content  style-scope paper-button x-scope paper-material-0" elevation="0"></paper-material>
<div class="content"></div>
<paper-material animated="" class="content  style-scope paper-button x-scope paper-material-0" elevation="0"></paper-material><paper-material animated="" class="content  style-scope paper-button x-scope paper-material-0" elevation="0"></paper-material>
</div>
```

What would make this happen, and how can I prevent it? Is it some kind of listener that gets called after using append?

If I go into inspector, and drag the content element into the mainContainer element, the page works fine. So something additional is happening with appendTo. As an additional check, I used setTimeout to call a function that called the appendTo method after 3 seconds to see if it had anything to do with methods that were called after the page was loaded.

Comment: Why are the two `html` snippets different? `.detach()` should not be necessary.

Comment: The 2nd snippet shows what's inside mainContainer after the appendTo call

Comment: Have not tried polymer. Can you create a stacksnippet or plnkr http://plnkr.co to reproduce issue?

Comment: It's solved. See below.

Answer (score 1):

Problem was that the paper-material elements have the same class name as the div I'm trying to move. I'm referencing the div by the same class name, so it will bring those over too. A quick solution was to assign the div an ID, and use detach by referencing the ID.